# org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [jar:file:{app}/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.2.9.jar!/META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml@47,31]

Tags: jsf-2, taglib

Our JSF application works fine when we deploy into tomcat, but, we are getting this error when we access the first page in UI. After that the error is not seen in other pages.

These are the jsf dependencies we are using:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

This is the error stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Error Loading Library: jar:file:../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/{app}/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.2.9.jar!/META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml
java.io.IOException: Error parsing [jar:file:../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/{app}/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.2.9.jar!/META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml]: 
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:410)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:431)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:144)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:95)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.bphx.cool.jsf.CustomHeaderFilter.doFilter(CustomHeaderFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [jar:file:../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/{app}/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.2.9.jar!/META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml@47,31]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.error(TagLibraryConfig.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:137)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1599)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1877)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:742)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1370)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1290)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3130)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:407)
    ... 31 more
```

What can I do to prevent this error log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [jar:file:../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/{app}/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-impl-2.2.9.jar!/META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml@47,31]

The error has manifested at line 47, character 31 of `/META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml` file in the `jsf-impl-2.2.9.jar` file. If you open the JAR with a ZIP tool and explore that taglib file around line 47, then you'll see:

```
44    <facelet-taglib xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
45                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
46                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd"
47                    version="2.2">
48        <namespace>http://mojarra.dev.java.net/mojarra_ext</namespace>
49        <tag>
```

It's the line with `version="2.2"`. This suggests a version conflict. To start, you need to make sure that the `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` file of your webapp is properly declared as per JSF 2.2 and not older:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <!-- Config here -->
</faces-config>
```

And you also need to make sure that the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` does not contain any Facelets 1.x JAR files. The package `com.sun.facelets.*` in the stack trace suggests presence of Facelets 1.x in runtime classpath, which is not right when using JSF 2.x as it already ships with Facelets 2.x bundled which is in package `com.sun.faces.facelets.*`.

Answer (score 4):

With all due respect I don't think that the chosen answer actually solves this problem. At least it didn't solve it for me.

The class which throws this exception (`com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler`) is coming from a standalone Facelet implementation. If you debug this issue you'll see that the root cause of this error is that XML's root element didn't match DTD (hint: `XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified`).

Given that TagLibraryConfig exists only in standalone Facelets you probably had the same issue as I did. What's happening is that when old Facelet's TagLibraryConfig scans classpath for all the facelet tag libraries under `META-INF/**/*.taglib.xml` it picks up Mojarra's `META-INF/mojarra_ext.taglib.xml` which is not fully compatible with the old DTD (e. g. version attribute didn't exist back then). It logs the failure and happily continues.

The best way to avoid this error is to start using Facelets built-in into JSF 2.x.

However, if you're stuck with Facelets 1.x (e. g. because you're using RichFaces 3.x) and curious about implications of ignoring this exception, you should know that all that tag library does is it provides three Mojarra-specific tags:

- `regexValidator` which duplicates `f:validateRegex` available since JSF 2.0
- `creditcardValidator` performs rudimentary credit card number format validation and Luhn check
- `focus` renders a little script that sets focus on an arbitrary element.

If you don't need those tags it's pretty safe to ignore this error. I considered a few ways to remove it from the logs but every solution (turning off the logger, custom context classloader or custom `FaceletViewHandler`) either had drawbacks or seemed like an overkill for such an unimportant issue.